# Is there a way to manipulate an embedded video using JS without APIs?

Tags: javascript, html, api, iframe, xss

I have the following Iframe attached to my HTML code:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

where the `src` can be any embedded video (like `https://www.youtube.com/embed/fWa5kDtyV0w`, for example). What I'm trying to do is the following: when the user pause the video, a function must be called to save the time of the video in a variable. However, I cannot find a way to this if, unless of using specifics APIs, like the one from Vimeo or Youtube (what I don't want to do, because some platforms don't have it). So, is there a way to interact with the video in the Iframe using JS or other stuff?

Extra information: In some of my tests, I got blocked by the browser by XSS.

Comment: There is not. If there were, it would be a security issue.